# Website on Shopify, want to have some site pages on a Wordpress App

Tags: woocommerce, dns, shopify

first time posting a question.

I have an e-commerce website on Shopify, and want to use a tool on WooCommerce (WordPress-WP). I want to point a URL to the WP pages without transferring the domain entirely. There will be links between the Shopify and WP pages, so it will be as if they are a part of the website, but are from two different platforms. Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to go about it?

I'd be willing to bet this is a very common issue, so I apologize for the repeat question, but I have been unsuccessful finding a solution or definitive answer that this is not possible. Pointing me in the direction of previously answered questions would also be appreciated.

Shopify URL: petschoiceplus.com
WP sample pages: petschoiceplus.wpcomstaging.com - test page that is not available

Thank you, Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I can create a subdomain that directs to the pages on WordPress. Was fairly simple to set up on my web registrar by creating new A and NS records under the primary domain.